# Trig Integral Practice Problem

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I solved this question using a different method than the answer book but the solutions don't produce the same result when we input x=1.

[image]

Comment: Yep, add the constant, both answers are the same then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculus teacher's pet response: +C!

Recall that $\sin^2 x = 1 - \cos^2 x$...Can you find a similar formula for $\sin^4 x$?

For reference, here's what the two answers look like when graphed (dropping the +C term): 
[image]

For another example of the same phenomenon, consider the integral $\int \sec^2 x \tan x d x$. Which of the two following answers is right?

1. using $u=\tan x$ and $du = \sec^2 x ~dx$, we have $$\int \sec^2 x \tan x ~dx = \int u ~du = \frac{1}{2} u^2 + C = \frac{1}{2} \tan^2 x +C$$
2. using $u=\sec x$ and $du = \sec x \tan x~ dx$ we have $$\int \sec^2 x \tan x dx = \int \sec x (\sec x \tan x)~ dx = \int u ~du = \frac{1}{2} u^2 +C = \frac{1}{2} \sec^2 x +C$$

Comment: Oooh I see, so if my answer without adding C is A(x) and the solution's answer without adding C is S(x), you're saying that even though A(1) =/= S(1), there exist C1, C2 such that A(1) + C1 = S(1) + C2. 

If so, that means it would be impossible for me to check my answer to match the solution's answer without using the exact same method of integration? Since choosing the correct C1, C2 is nearly impossible without graphing.

Comment: Yep, although note that we're finding a constant that works for all $x$, not just $x=1$. In the example I gave, recall that $1+\tan^2 x = \sec^2 x$. As such, $\frac{1}{2} \sec^2 x = \frac{1}{2} \tan^2 x + \frac{1}{2}$. The extra $1/2$ term just got sucked into the constant of integration (the +C). You can do a similar argument to see that your answer and the solution are the same in a similar vein by manipulating trig identities around.

Comment: Using your notation for $A(x)$ and $S(x)$, a more precise way to state this would be that there is a constant $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $A(x) + c = S(x)$ for all $x$, and therefore we have the same family of solutions.

Comment: As another hypothetical, suppose my answer is $S(x) = \sin^2 x +C$ and your answer is $A(X) = -\frac{1}{2} \cos (2x) +C$. But $\sin^2 x = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \cos (2x) = - \frac{1}{2} \cos(2x) + c$ for some constant $c$, so we really have the same answer, we just expressed it differently. Same as if my answer was $S(x) = x+C$ and your answer was $A(x) = x+3+C$